# How do I choose the image rotation axis, Magick++?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I want to rotate an image around a certain point in the image. I am using Magic++.  How can I choose the axis of rotation?   There is the rotate function but it only allows me to set the number of degrees and not choose an axis.

Comment: I think you'll need to create your own transformation matrix -- take a look at [affineTransform](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/Magick++/classMagick_1_1Image.html#aa7adc4fe21954d8ba50ba4343a47738b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create an affine transformation to map the rotation & transition. Example...

```cpp
Magick::Image img("rose:");
double
    originX = 50,
    originY = 75,
    angle = 45.0,
    radians = angle * atan2(1, 1)/45.0,
    sx = cos( radians ),
    rx = sin( radians ),
    ry = -rx,
    sy = sx,
    tx = originX * sx - originY * rx,
    ty = originX * rx + originY * sx;
Magick::DrawableAffine matrix(sx, rx, ry, sy, tx, ty);
img.virtualPixelMethod(Magick::TransparentVirtualPixelMethod);
img.affineTransform(matrix);
```

Detailed examples of creating affine matrices, including share & origin transitions, can be found [Affine Matrix Transforms](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/affine/#affine_rot) usages documents. Includes useful links to [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) scripts.

Comment: I think you forgot to add `originX` to `tx` and add `originY` to `ty`.